# Are questions for webcomics but also somewhat about writing on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've just started writing a webcomic and was wondering if I can ask questions about it here. Obviously I won't ask 'how to draw X', but probably more about the layout of the strip and timing, as well as introducing new characters. Here's a few examples;

> How can I spread this dialogue throughout the strip?

> Should I introduce this character with method A, B, or C?

> Does this strip layout make sense and is it easy to read?

And others will generally fall around these subjects. I feel like 1 and 2 fall under 'proof reading' and 'help me write X', and 3 is more of a visual question that is probably not on topic here.

I just wanted to check in case these types of questions are on-topic here. If not on topic for writing SE, is there another SE that these questions might be more on-topic for? Any recommendations on how to make them on topic for Writing SE while still keeping them about the webcomic?

Answer (score 4):

In general terms - so long as the questions meet the normal guidelines and about the *writing* aspects of the web-comic there's no reason they can't be asked here. It's a medium like any other.

To look at your more specific examples:

> How can I spread this dialogue throughout the strip?

I think if you can make this to be more of a *general* case, even if you provide a specific example you are ok, e.g:

> I'm having trouble pacing dialogue across the length of the comic strips I write, such as in this example: [example] where all the dialogue feels crammed into the 3rd panel. How can I avoid this problem when writing?

Secondly:

> Should I introduce this character with method A, B, or C?

It's hard to be sure without seeing a real question but I think this risks falling into  "what to write?", and it might be hard to avoid a situation where all answers were equally valid and the question became essentially a poll.

Finally:

> Does this strip layout make sense and is it easy to read?

As written this feels like even if you weren't asking about a visual aspect it would be a straight up critique request which would be off-topic anyway.